# Passing data from child to parent component ( child loaded via routing)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this issue.

**Chat** is a parent component and it has **Messages** child component. I have url-s, `/chat/`, `/chat/:id`. So i can get `:id` param in **Messages** component with **RouteParams**, but i need that `:id` in **Chat** component. So if i load `/chat/46` then **Chat** component knows that 46  `:id`

If i am loading it as directive something like `<messages (Event)="handleEvent()"></messages>` than i can pass it via **EventEmitter** and Output, but if i load component through `<router-outlet>` how i can pass value back to the parent ? EventEmitter and Output doesn't work in this case. Maybe there is something in router that can do the trick.

Comment: https://github.com/escardin/angular2-community-faq/blob/master/services.md#how-do-i-communicate-between-components-using-a-shared-service

Comment: Well it's pretty good idea but it doesn't work. Chat component has subscription but it doesn't provide any data, so **.subscribe(resp => console.log(resp))** shows nothing. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: One thing that is working now is **router.isActive()** which i use in template but i need data in the class. Also **isActive()** binded to the property and constantly invoking as i see in logs so it's not the best solution i guess. In general binding function to the property in Angular2 bad idea because of pretty complex change detection engine that forces that function to be invoked often.

Comment: Here is plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/y7PZONWELeG4f2Ywbw4k - it's pretty strange that it's not working because  message passing work for http requests that return observable. @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by interaction between components as suggested. 
Here is an example:

component-interaction.service.ts

```
id = new Subject<number>();
idEmitter$ = this.id.asObservable();

sendId(id:number){
    this.id.next(id);
}
```

messages.component.ts

```
constructor(private router:Router, private cci:ComponentInteractionService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.cci.sendId(this.router.param); // sending your params the way you get it
}
```

chat.component.ts

```
id:number;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private cci:ComponentInteractionService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.cci.idEmitter$.subscribe(res =>this.id = res);
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

This way the id changes are subscribed and parent can preety much get it every time.

**EDIT:** Changed the EventEmitter to Subject and asObservable combo as advised by Angular team and added unsubscribe to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use Dependency Injection to inject a SessionService instance (always the same instance) both in Chat (parent) and Message (Child).

When the Child has a value to communicate to the Parent it can store it into the SessionService; if  the SessionService instance is the same (which is granted by standard Dependency Induction use) than the Parent should be able to catch what Child wants to communicate.

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi it doesn't work. Value is undefined after change.